# scroll-snap-type: x not working on mobile but oworks on web

Tags: html, css, carousel

I've implemented this carosel with automatic X scrolling:

https://codepen.io/Schepp/pen/WNbQByE

Works great!  One thing, it does NOT work great on mobile.  It's stuck on the first image and does not work.  happens on iOS and android, and also even happens when looking at inspector (cmd+shift+c) and toggling device toolbar (cmd+shift+m) for viewing for mobile.

Why is scroll-snap not working for mobile?

This is reproducible on the codepen link when inspecting toggling device toolbar as stated above, but if it helps, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="about-slides-container">
    <section class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
        <ol class="carousel__viewport">
        <li id="carousel__slide2"
            tabindex="0"
            class="carousel__slide">
            <img class="canvas-block-image about-me-image" src="./assets/9.jpeg" alt="About">
            <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="carousel__slide1"
            tabindex="0"
            class="carousel__slide">
            <img class="canvas-block-image about-me-image" src="./assets/8.jpeg" alt="About">
            <div class="carousel__snapper">
            </div>
        </li>

        </aside>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    @keyframes tonext {
        75% {
        left: 0;
        }
        95% {
        left: 100%;
        }
        98% {
        left: 100%;
        }
        99% {
        left: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes tostart {
        75% {
        left: 0;
        }
        95% {
        left: -300%;
        }
        98% {
        left: -300%;
        }
        99% {
        left: 0;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes snap {
        96% {
        scroll-snap-align: center;
        }
        97% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
        }
        99% {
        scroll-snap-align: none;
        }
        100% {
        scroll-snap-align: center;
        }
    }

  
    ol, li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .carousel {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #0003);
        perspective: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .carousel__viewport {
        pointer-events: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        counter-reset: item;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
        -webkit-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    }
    
    .carousel__slide {
        position: relative;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        width: 100%;
        counter-increment: item;
    }
    
    .carousel__snapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        scroll-snap-align: center;
    }
    
    @media (hover: hover) {
        .carousel__snapper {
        animation-name: tonext, snap;
        animation-timing-function: ease;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        }
    
        .carousel__slide:last-child .carousel__snapper {
        animation-name: tostart, snap;
        }
    }
    
    @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
        .carousel__snapper {
        animation-name: none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its working on mobile

Comment: It's working on mobile the same as on desktop. It's buggy, but there's no difference between mobile and desktop from what I can see. Are you sure that the problem you're describing is the real problem?

Comment: working fine from my android MI note 7 pro device

Comment: "mobile" and "PC" are far to vague. Which browsers on PC and which browsers on Mobile have you tested? Are they ***all*** showing the **same** bug?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, and cool example! I think there's a few things here. First depending on the device you're using, you might be running into browser support issues: https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll%20snap

But I would question the use of a pure CSS slider unless it's just an experiment. It's inherently buggy and the problem isn't just on mobile, it breaks pretty quickly on desktop as well. You've also got things like each slide needing its own pair of prev/next buttons which are intrinsically linked to the slide numbers.

Is there a particular reason you've decided to go for a CSS only solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="about-slides-container">
    <section class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
        <ol class="carousel__viewport">
        <li id="carousel__slide2"
            tabindex="0"
            class="carousel__slide">
            <img class="canvas-block-image about-me-image" src="./assets/9.jpeg" alt="About">
            <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
        </li>
        <li id="carousel__slide1"
            tabindex="0"
            class="carousel__slide">
            <img class="canvas-block-image about-me-image" src="./assets/8.jpeg" alt="About">
            <div class="carousel__snapper">
            </div>
        </li>
(Add)---></ol>
 (Remove)---></aside>
    </section>
</div>
```